# How to use a variable to modify the Browser Endpoint in Node Red

Tags: nodes, node-modules, iot, node-red, opc-ua

I am a beginner in node red, I work now with IIoT-OPCUA, I need to connect my server to my client OPC UA through an interface in node red Dashboard and then access all the data from the server.
I want  to modify the Browser Endpoint  from a text input in node red Dashboard. So how can I access and modify the Browser endpoint dynamically.  I tried to set a variable inside the Browser Endpoint but is not working.
thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the source code for the node, there is no support for dynamically changing the Endpoint (which also should point to a config node, not a raw string)

Comment: OK, I use this node to browse different kepserver, do you have any idea which node I can use instead of this node and that I can mention a variable in the endpoint.thank you very much .